# How to filter a svelte store using a dynamic filter

Tags: observable, reactive-programming, svelte

I have a derived store which has to filter an entries object using HTML selects for the filter. Now I introduced an extra filter store (observable) to force the derived store callback to run when the filter store changes.

But is it possible to trigger the callback in the derived store below without the filter store when the filter changes? Do I need this extra store here?
The below code works fine. I'am curious.

```
import { writable, derived } from 'svelte/store';
import { entries } from './../stores/entries.js';

export const filter = writable({
  // to update filter use: $filter.kind = ... 
  // or: filter.update(o => Object.assign(o, {kind: .., batchId: ...}));
  batchId: 'all',
  kind: 'all',
});

let list, total;

export const view = derived(
  [filter, entries], 
  ([$filter, $entries], set) => {

    total = 0;

    if ($entries) {
      // filter by HTML selects: kind, batchId
      list = Object.keys($entries.map).sort().reduce((a, key) => {
        if ((['all', $entries.map[key].description.kind].includes($filter.kind))
          && (['all', $entries.map[key].parentId].includes($filter.batchId))) {
            total += $entries.map[key].grossValue;
            a.push($entries.map[key]);
        };
        return a;  
      }, []);
      set({list, total});
    };

    return () => {
      set(null);
    };
  }, null
);
```

**Update: a pseudo derived writeable using a custom store**

```
import { writable, derived } from 'svelte/store';
import { entries } from './../stores/entries.js';

let list, total;

const filter = writable({batchId: 'all', kind: 'all'});

export const view = () => {
  const viewDerived = derived([filter, entries], 
    ([$filter, $entries]) => {

      total = 0;
      if ($entries) {
        // filter by HTML selects: kind, batchId
        list = Object.keys($entries.map).sort().reduce((a, key) => {
          if ((['all', $entries.map[key].description.kind].includes($filter.kind))
            && (['all', $entries.map[key].parentId].includes($filter.batchId))) {
              total += $entries.map[key].grossValue;
              a.push($entries.map[key]);
          };
          return a;  
        }, []);
        return {list, total};
      } else return null;

    }
  );
  // custom store methods
  return {
    subscribe: viewDerived.subscribe,
    set: filter.set,
    update: (obj) => filter.update(o => Object.assign(o, obj)),
    reset: () => filter.set({batchId: 'all', kind: 'all'}),
  };
}();
```

Comment: Is this running in a component? `derived` doesn't really work outside component since Svelte doesn't keep track of dependencies in `.js` files.

Comment: Stores do and works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extract the logic from the derived store into a function / object you control yourself, with an API to manually trigger an update... But that would not be a good idea. That would break some encapsulation for no benefit and all.

Your `writable` + `derived` solution is, IMO, the most straightforward and elegant solution. It explicitly outlines data dependencies, and cleanly separate concerns, with no arcane code involved. It also provides Svelte what it needs to monitor changes, and manages subscriptions automatically for you, with the finest granularity.

This is a nice pattern, and it is perfectly appropriated for your use case. I would keep it like this.

Comment: OK rixo and thnx. Does it matter if I use store.set / update or $store bindings and $store.prop assigments to change the filter?

Comment: Nope, `$store` assignment internally uses the store's `set` method. This is a very thin layer of syntactic sugar, so it's exactly the same.

Comment: I noticed the callback is running a couple of times when I change a filter prop. I did not figure out yet the relation between filter prop changes and callbacks. For instance: The callback in the above example fires three times if I change the select binding (change the select option). Sometimes the callback runs six times.

Comment: I get only one update in a simple case: https://svelte.dev/repl/f8d2249416b845faa2389d33d0af490f?version=3.22.2. That being said, I've recently seen multiple reports of people having double updates (in reactive blocks) when using binding in another component. This might be related. Also, if you have multiple `$store.foo` assignment that get triggered in series, then it's possible that you get multiple update. So maybe, with using `set` / `update` yourself, you could "batch" those changes, in fact...

Comment: Yes. The selects bindings from other components.  And I use update to batch filter changes. But a checkbox binding also fires twice using: bind:checked={$entryFilter.compact}. It would be nice to have a tool for Svelte which logs the source of these dirty / reactive signals. Thnx again and I will try to find the source.